# Extract values for all data frames inside of a list to create a new data frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, function, lapply

I have a list of data frames in R (see image below). I want to create a unique data frame outside of the list with a column that has the information about the Name for all the data frames, another column the data about the Latitud, another with the Longitud, etc.

[image]

I am trying using `lapply`, but without success:

`lapply(Stations.metadata, function(x) df = data.frame(Name=x$Name, Latitud=x$Latitud, Longitud=x$Longitud, Coordinate.System=x$Coordinate.System, Drainage.Area=x$Drainage.Area))`

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `purrr::map_dfr(Stations.metadata, ~.x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried creating a list similar to yours

Do either of these two

```r
my.list <- apply(iris[1:4,], 1, as.list)
str(my.list)
#> List of 4
#>  $ 1:List of 5
#>   ..$ Sepal.Length: chr "5.1"
#>   ..$ Sepal.Width : chr "3.5"
#>   ..$ Petal.Length: chr "1.4"
#>   ..$ Petal.Width : chr "0.2"
#>   ..$ Species     : chr "setosa"
#>  $ 2:List of 5
#>   ..$ Sepal.Length: chr "4.9"
#>   ..$ Sepal.Width : chr "3.0"
#>   ..$ Petal.Length: chr "1.4"
#>   ..$ Petal.Width : chr "0.2"
#>   ..$ Species     : chr "setosa"
#>  $ 3:List of 5
#>   ..$ Sepal.Length: chr "4.7"
#>   ..$ Sepal.Width : chr "3.2"
#>   ..$ Petal.Length: chr "1.3"
#>   ..$ Petal.Width : chr "0.2"
#>   ..$ Species     : chr "setosa"
#>  $ 4:List of 5
#>   ..$ Sepal.Length: chr "4.6"
#>   ..$ Sepal.Width : chr "3.1"
#>   ..$ Petal.Length: chr "1.5"
#>   ..$ Petal.Width : chr "0.2"
#>   ..$ Species     : chr "setosa"
#1
purrr::map_dfr(my.list, ~.x)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#>   <chr>        <chr>       <chr>        <chr>       <chr>  
#> 1 5.1          3.5         1.4          0.2         setosa 
#> 2 4.9          3.0         1.4          0.2         setosa 
#> 3 4.7          3.2         1.3          0.2         setosa 
#> 4 4.6          3.1         1.5          0.2         setosa
#2
do.call(rbind, lapply(my.list, as.data.frame))
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>